# What is the justification of replacing classical variables with operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, operators

Is is because of Ehrenfest theorem that implies that the Hamiltonian constructed as such by replacing will lead the expected position and momentum to behave like their classical counterparts? Or is there another reason?

Comment: An easy but unsatisfactory answer is: Because it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Name of concept: Replace classical variables by quantum operators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/544748/)

Comment: You can read about Heisenberg's reasoning for the development of matrix mechanics on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_mechanics#Heisenberg's_reasoning. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg%27s_entryway_to_matrix_mechanics

Comment: But rigorously speaking, shouldn't we prove that this the only possible way to make the expected position and momentum to behave like their classical counterparts? Otherwise I don't see why the results obtained as such would represent reality at quantum scales ?

Comment: It's not the only way to represent position and momentum quantum mechanically. In the path integral formalism, there are no operators. You have to distinguish the *representation* of physics from actual physics. There are always multiple mathematical representations of the same physics.

Comment: To add to @Andrew comment: Moreover, there is no a-priori reason why anything that you write down on a sheet of paper would correspond to reality. An instrumentalist or anti-realist would argue that the only physical thing are measurement results. Everything else is a way to make predictions, which can work or not, but does not tell you anything about the 'nature' of the world.

Comment: thank you for your comments, what I mean is that for example if you take the Hamiltonian of the classical harmonic oscillator and replace x and p by the corresponding operators, there is no proof, in principle, that there is a system in the reality that obeys this new Hamiltonian. The conditions in Ehrenfest theorem are basically necessary (to match experience at large scales) but not sufficient. Sorry if this doesn't make sense

Comment: It doesn't make sense indeed. In deformation quantization, you **do not** replace classical phase space variables with operators: you just tweak their composition laws to something different (*-multiplication) which is consistent and agrees with observed phenomena at small scales, in contrast to classical mechanics.